# getPackageManager() gives error when used in static class

Tags: java, android

So the following code works fine when placed in an activity but when placed as a static method in a static java class getPackageManager generates an error...not sure why

```
public String VersionInfo(){
    String version = "";
    try {
        version = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    return version;
}
```

Comment: Please learn java's basics...  Every non static method of the class  can be only called with this class instance.

Comment: non static method can't be call from static method directly

Answer (score 1):

You need to call getPackageManager() with a context if calling outside an activity. Pass the context in the versionInfo method and use that to get the package manager. Something like this:

```
public String VersionInfo(final Context context){
String version = "";
try {
    version = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
}

return version;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way:

In your `Activity` you can call like this:

```
Test.VersionInfo(mActivity);  // where  mActivity is nothing but current context this. you can use this instead.
```

This is **static** class below:

```
static class Test{

         public static String VersionInfo(Context ctx){
             String version = "";
             try {
                 version = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
             } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                 Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
             }

             return version;
         }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method

```
/** Return PackageManager instance to find global package information. */
    public abstract PackageManager getPackageManager();
```

is defined in the `Context` class. So to access you need a context object or you can access in sub class of `Context`.
Following is the hierarchy for the `Activity`-

```
Context (android.content)
-ContextWrapper (android.content)
 -ContextThemeWrapper (android.view)
  -Activity (android.app)
```

So the Activity has Access to the method `getPackageManager()`.